# how to get better control of window sizes in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, text, wxpython, size

I am trying to build a GUI with wxPython.  (BTW, this problem is from work, and I am typing from home because I can't access this site from work.  Maybe that's a firewall problem?  Anyway, that's why I'm doing this from memory and can't give any screenshots.)  My first collection of controls is a vertical stack.  A static text is on top.  Below it is a BoxSizer holding three text controls added horizontally.  Below that is another static text.  On the bottom is one final text control.  The problem is the three text controls in the BoxSizer.  If I add them without the proportion argument, everything generally looks good.  But I want them to be different sizes.  So, when I add the proportion arguments (4, 3, and 16 if that matters) the three text controls become far too large and greatly increase the width of the frame.  The bottom text control expands to equal the length of the three top text controls too.  So, I can get the overall size of everything right if I give up the proportions of the three text controls.  Or I can get their proportions right if I give up the overall horizontal size that I want.  But I really need both.  Is there a way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A little example of code would help a lot.

I could not understand how setting the proportion of the widgets in the sizer increases the width of the frame!

Anyways, you can set the size of the textctrl widgets when creating them, which might take care of both the proportion and overall size issues. You will only need to calculate the appropriate sizes beforehand.

If it helps in any way, here's an example of a frame with the specifications you provided:

```
import wx

class Frame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 400,400 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.panel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        sizer_0 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.static_text_top = wx.StaticText( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Something Something", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.static_text_top.Wrap( -1 )
        sizer_0.Add( self.static_text_top, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        sizer_01 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        sizer_01.Add( self.textCtrl1, 4, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.textCtrl2 = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        sizer_01.Add( self.textCtrl2, 3, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.textCtrl3 = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        sizer_01.Add( self.textCtrl3, 16, wx.ALL, 5 )


        sizer_0.Add( sizer_01, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0 )

        self.static_text_middle = wx.StaticText( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Something else", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.static_text_middle.Wrap( -1 )
        sizer_0.Add( self.static_text_middle, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.textCtrl4 = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        sizer_0.Add( self.textCtrl4, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.panel.SetSizer( sizer_0 )
        self.panel.Layout()
        sizer_0.Fit( self.panel )
        sizer.Add( self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 0 )


        self.SetSizer( sizer )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Frame()
    app.MainLoop()
```